# MediaWiki Groups that override rights from other Groups

Tags: media, mediawiki, wiki

I am running a small MediaWiki. 
It has the standard groups: all, user, bureaucrat, bot and sysop all with matching rights.
But some of these rights are doubled so "all" may use the writeAPI and "users" may use the writeAPI too, so far no problem.
Now I want to restrict some accounts rights so they can't do anything else than reading.
Therefor I wanted to add a new group, wich overrides all other existing group rights of the account added to it.
So anybody in this group may only read articles no matter what other group they are in.
If you are added to this group it takes rights from you rather than granting you new ones 
Is this possible, or do I have to add a new "writingUser" group and add anybody to this new group, remove the all rights from the standard "user" and "all" group and then remove accounts from the "writingUser" group to do the restriction... 
I could not find anything like this in the web, were I just looking for the wrong thing or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$wgRevokePermissions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions), e.g. `$wgRevokePermissions['punished-user']['edit'] = false;` but you'll have to revoke every permission you don't want them to have explicitly. Also, you might consider simply blocking them:)